# How to write subquery in querydsl?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have used in my project querydsl, hibernate and spring data jpa.I wrote this native query and working fine.but How can I write this query in Querydsl.

```
List<OpenChart> openChartList = (List<OpenChart>) getEntityManager()
.createNativeQuery( "select * from (select * from open_chart order by id desc ) open_chart where user_id="+userId+" group by patient_chart_id order by id",OpenChart.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: I don't think this question qualify for downvote instead of getting answer. I want to convert this code using querydsl because I have used mostly querydsl in my project. I searched for querydsl subquery example but did not find suitable example. So I put my question here.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [JPASubQuery](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.1/apidocs/com/mysema/query/jpa/JPASubQuery.html)

from the [manual](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.1/reference/html/ch02.html)

> 2.1.13. Subqueries To create a subquery you create a JPASubQuery instance, define the query parameters via from, where etc and use
>   unique or list to create a subquery, which is just a type-safe
>   Querydsl expression for the query. unique is used for a unique
>   (single) result and list for a list result.

```
 QEmployee employee = QEmployee.employee; 
 QEmployee e = new QEmployee("e"); 
 query.from(employee)
      .where(employee.weeklyhours.gt(
           new JPASubQuery().from(employee.department.employees, e)
                            .where(e.manager.eq(employee.manager))
                            .unique(e.weeklyhours.avg())
       )).list(employee);
```

> For Hibernate based sub query usage, use the HibernateSubQuery
>   instead.

Answer (score 2):

I prepared an example of how to use a subquery in the similar scenario to what you described, hope you can help and provide the basis for its implementation:

```
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = new SQLQuery(connection, PostgresTemplates.builder().quote().newLineToSingleSpace()
            .printSchema().build());

    ListSubQuery<Tuple> listSubQuery = new SQLSubQuery().from(QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords).orderBy(QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords.usuNummat.desc()).list(QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords.all());

    QUsersPasswords qSubquery = new QUsersPasswords("subquery");

    sqlQuery.from(listSubQuery.as("subquery")).limit(10);

    sqlQuery.list(qSubquery.all());
```

Comment: I am trying to implement according to your example

Comment: ListSubQuery<Tuple> listSubQuery = new JPASubQuery()
    .from(QOpenChart.openChart)
    .orderBy(QOpenChart.openChart.id.desc())
    .list(QOpenChart.openChart.);
  QOpenChart qOpenChart = new QOpenChart("subquery");
  List<OpenChart> openCharts = pageableQuery(pageable)
    .from((EntityPath<?>) listSubQuery.as("subquery"))
    .where(qOpenChart.userId.id.eq(userId))
    .groupBy(qOpenChart.patientChart.id)
    .orderBy(qOpenChart.id.asc()).list(qOpenChart);

Comment: at line1 , I am not finding any all method and at last line its asking for entity where listsubquery is a list of tuple.I tried to cast like( EntityPath<?>) listSubQuery.as("subquery")

Comment: but its throwing exception

Comment: @Santosh Narna, my example is QueryDSL-SQL which is used for native queries. If you need a object, you should uses QueryDSL-JPA. For examplo, instead ListSubQuery<Tuple> your return should be ListSubQuery<OpenChart>. I dont need any project with querydsl-jpa for run some tests, sorry.

Comment: you are right. I am looking for Querydsl-jpa example for above code.Because I have used Querydsl-jpa in my project. I tried  ListSubQuery<OpenChart>  but  getiing error. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarlonPatrick: From your code there is: QUsersPasswords.usersPasswords.all()    ; But in my case: queryFactory.select(customer.all).from(customer) <-- Compile error, because [ERROR] cannot find symbol : variable all . Could you please show me how to have method .all() for customer